# Emulating Firebase Database Trigger Function Error: the service "firebaseio.com" is not yet supported

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions, firebase-cli

**UPDATE: SOLVED! The `firebase-tools` npm package needed updating to the latest version.**

---

I am trying to emulate/test my cloud function (specifically a database trigger) using Firebase's `firebase experimental:functions:shell` command in my terminal.

Here is the result, my HTTP functions emulate but I get errors for every **Firebase Database** trigger function:

```
Your requested "node" version "6" doesn't match your global version "8"
✔  functions: Emulator started at http://localhost:5001
i  functions: Watching "/Users/****/Documents/Websites/***** - Other/cloud-functions/" for Cloud Functions...
⚠  Default "firebase-admin" instance created!
⚠  Ignoring trigger "CF_NAME_HIDDEN_1" because the service "firebaseio.com" is not yet supported.
⚠  Ignoring trigger "CF_NAME_HIDDEN_2" because the service "firebaseio.com" is not yet supported.
⚠  Ignoring trigger "CF_NAME_HIDDEN_3" because the service "firebaseio.com" is not yet supported.
i  functions: HTTP trigger initialized at http://localhost:5001/****-****/us-central1/CF_NAME_HIDDEN_4
```

**I do not understand why I am getting this error or what it means:**

> Ignoring trigger ... because the service "firebaseio.com" is not yet supported.

My package.json includes:

```
"firebase": "4.6.2",
"firebase-admin": "^7.4.0",
"firebase-functions": "^2.2.1",
...
"devDependencies": {
   "firebase-functions-test": "^0.1.6"
},
```

Comment: https://github.com/firebase/firebase-tools/issues/1299

Comment: @DougStevenson So it was fixed in `6.9.3`? I updated my tools to the latest version only 9 days ago because of another breaking change. You guys are moving fast at HQ.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**SOLVED:**

It was simply because firebase pushed a small change to their `firebase-tools` and the 0.1 version difference was enough to break the emulation.

Simply running `npm install -g firebase-tools` fixed the issue.

The package versions went from `firebase-tools@6.9.2` to `firebase-tools@6.10.0`...